# Cannot import kotlin.reflect.full.* in intellij

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, annotations

I am going through the Kotlin Bootcamp for Programmers course on the android website and can't seem to import the above lib `import kotlin.reflect.full.*` I simply get an "Unresolved reference: full" error. I think it might have been deprecated but can't find its replacement, any help would be great

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not part of the Kotlin standard library. Add the following dependency to your `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
```

Comment: Thanks, this will help when I am in an android project, but how do i add this to a Kotlin project in IntelliJ Idea

Comment: Go to `File` > `Project Structure` > `Libraries` > `New Project Library` > `From Maven Repository` > Search for "kotlin-reflect" and add the correct version from the results.